# Run time error error when trying to export data from XLS to a named XML file

Tags: excel, vba

I've written my first VBA macro to export rows of data from XLS to separate named XML files in a specific location. My initial, simplified tests went fine but the full version errors with the message:

Run-time error 91: object variable or with block variable not set

macro:

```
  Sub XML()
 sTemplateXML = _
"<?xml version='1.0'?>" + vbNewLine + _
 "<FromEmail>" + "</FromEmail>" + vbNewLine + _
 "<FromName>" + "</FromName>" + vbNewLine + _
 "<ToEmail>" + "</ToEmail>" + vbNewLine + _
 "<CCAddresses>" + "</CCAddresses>" + vbNewLine + _
 "<BCCAddresses>" + "</BCCAddresses>" + vbNewLine + _
 "<ReplyTo>" + "</ReplyTo>" + vbNewLine + _
 "<Subject>" + "</Subject>" + vbNewLine + _
 "<Body>" + "</Body>" + vbNewLine + _
 "</EmailValues>" + vbNewLine

 Set doc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
 doc.async = False
 doc.validateOnParse = False
 doc.resolveExternals = False

With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
lLastRow = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For lRow = 2 To lLastRow
sFile = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 13).Value
sfromemail = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 3).Value
sFromname = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 2).Value
sToEmail = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 5).Value
sCCAddresses = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 7).Value
sBCCAddresses = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 8).Value
sReplyTo = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 4).Value
sSubject = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 11).Value
sBody = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 12).Value


doc.LoadXML sTemplateXML
doc.getElementsbyTagName("FromEmail")(0).appendChild 
doc.createTextNode(sfromemail) (ERROR POPS UP HERE)
doc.getElementsbyTagName("FromName")(0).appendChild 
doc.createTextNode(sFromname)
doc.getElementsbyTagName("ToEmail")(0).appendChild 
doc.createTextNode(sToEmail)
doc.getElementsbyTagName("CCAddresses")(0).appendChild 
doc.createTextNode(sCCAddresses)
doc.getElementsbyTagName("BCCAddresses")(0).appendChild 
doc.createTextNode(sBCCAddresses)
doc.getElementsbyTagName("ReplyTo")(0).appendChild 
doc.createTextNode(sReplyTo)
doc.getElementsbyTagName("Subject")(0).appendChild 
doc.createTextNode(sSubject)
doc.getElementsbyTagName("Body")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sBody)

doc.Save sFile
Next

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: *ALERT, ALERT!* - There is a  *way* easier way to convert Excel to XML - I'd recommend taking a look [here](http://www.meadinkent.co.uk/xl_xml1.htm) and adapting your code to the boilerplate code written there.

Comment: @dwirony hey thanks for responding :) would this apply if i want to convert rows of data to separate xml files?

Comment: Yes. The idea is that instead of using elements/childs/nodes, just print your XML files line by line.

Comment: @dwirony hi sorry im very new to this would i run that marco on that site on the data i already have entered in excel (emails) and run the macro? sorry super new still trying to learn :)!

Comment: Your doc is missing an opening `<EmailValues>`

Comment: @TimWilliams hi tim wow so silly! thank you so much!!! :)

Comment: @TimWilliams hey tim thank you for the code below!! i tried running it with my macro however i get the 'run time error - 2147024773 (8007007b)': the filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.'    and     doc.Save rw.Cells(13).Value is highlighted any ideas?

Comment: Most likely whatever is in column 13 of that row is not a valid file name/path

Comment: @TimWilliams hi tim so i have the following entered in one of the lines "c:\temp\xmls\emailtest.xml"  in the xmls folder in my directory i do not have anything saved at the moment it is an empty folder should i only not have the file name that i want it to save as in that column either?

Comment: also here is a line from my original code that gave me the same error:  sFile = "C:\Temp\XMLs\" & ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(lrow, 1).Value & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(lrow, 10).Value
        and in column 10 all it was was data like 'testemail.xml' @TimWilliams

Comment: I can't really tell what the problem is - as long as the filename is valid and the destination folder exists (and you have permission to write to it) then you should be OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be much tidier with a little refactoring:

```
Sub SaveRowsToXml()
    Dim lLastRow As Long, lrow As Long
    With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        lLastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        For lrow = 2 To lLastRow
            SaveToXml .Rows(lrow)
        Next lrow
    End With
End Sub

'save a single row of data as XML
Sub SaveToXml(rw As Range)
    Dim doc As Object, r
    Set doc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    doc.appendChild doc.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0'")
    Set r = doc.createElement("EmailValues") '<< create the root element
    doc.appendChild r
    'append child nodes
    r.appendChild NodeWithContent(doc, "FromEmail", rw.Cells(3).Value)
    r.appendChild NodeWithContent(doc, "FromName", rw.Cells(2).Value)
    r.appendChild NodeWithContent(doc, "ToEmail", rw.Cells(5).Value)
    r.appendChild NodeWithContent(doc, "CCAddresses", rw.Cells(7).Value)
    'etc
    'etc
    'Debug.Print doc.XML
    doc.Save rw.Cells(13).Value
    Set doc = Nothing
End Sub

'return a named element with content
Function NodeWithContent(doc, nodename, content)
    Dim el
    Set el = doc.createElement(nodename)
    el.appendChild doc.createTextNode(content)
    Set NodeWithContent = el
End Function
```